# How to get most recent balance from many users balances?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table `users` and `transactions`. `transactions` table has relation with users two table format like below

```
users 
id  name    email        created
1   a       a@mail.com   12-03-01
2   b       b@mail.com   11-03-01


Transactions
id   user_id  balance 
1    1        250 
2    1        550 
3    2        50 
4    2        1000
```

I need last inserted users balance from transactions table with all users information. I am new in sql.

So I have tried below code

```
select * from transactions 
where id in (select max(id) from transactions group by user_id)
INNER JOIN users on transactions.user_id=users.id
```

It's giving me syntax error near inner join.Have I made any mistake in inner join ? or I am in wrong direction ?

Comment: `join`s come **BEFORE** `where` clauses. `select ... from ... join ... where ... `

Comment: @SatuSultana . . . Do you want one row returned or one row per user?  Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the balance, then a correlated subquery might be faster:

```
select u.*,
       (select t.balance
        from transactions t
        where t.user_id = u.id
        order by t.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as MostRecentBalance
from users u;
```

For maximum performance, you want an index on `transactions(user_id, id desc, balance)`.

The reason this is faster is because it avoids the aggregation on the entire `transactions` table.  This is even more important if you are only selecting a subset of users.

EDIT:

I originally read this question as one row per user.  However, if you only want one row returned -- for the last insert into `transactions` -- then a simpler method is:

```
select u.*, t.balance
from users u join
     transactions t
     on u.id = t.user_id
order by t.id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans.Top one is correct I need all users data not only one.

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN should be part of the FROM statement so it should look more like the code below.

```
select * 
from transactions ts
INNER JOIN users 
ON (transactions.user_id=users.id)
where ts.id in 
           (
             select max(transactions.id) 
             from transactions 
             group by user_id
           );
```

edited to clarify which id is in use as per Gordons suggestion

Comment: I am getting this error 
#1052 - Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Comment: @HardLeeWorking . . . It is a good idea to qualify all columns names when you write a query.  I would suggest that you fix your query to avoid the error that Satu has pointed out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added in clarification as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

2 simple methods.

A sub query to get the lastest transaction, and from that all the transaction details and then the user

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN transactions
ON users.id = transactions.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM transactions
) sub0
ON transactions.id = sub0.max_id
```

Or you could try ordering by the id descending with a limit of 1:-

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN transactions
ON users.id = transactions.user_id
ORDER BY transactions.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

EDIT

To get the last transaction for all users then you could use the following:-

```
SELECT *
FROM users
INNER JOIN transactions
ON users.id = transactions.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY user_id
) sub0
ON transactions.id = sub0.max_id
ON transactions.user_id = sub0.user_id
```

Comment: Here I get only one data but I need all users last inserted balance.

Comment: I have added a solution for that